# How to add apostrophe to a paste function in R?

Tags: r, function, vector, paste

Here is the data

```
x <- c(0:10)
y <- c(10:0)
test <- paste(x, y, sep="/")
data.test <- data.frame(x,y,test)
```

The current output for data.test is `0/10 1/9 2/8 ...`  I want to make it `"0/10 "1/9 "2/8 ...`

Comment: `test <- paste(as.character(x), as.character(y), sep="/")` shall do the trick

Comment: When you do `paste(paste0("\"", x), y, sep = "/")` you will notice that the output looks like `"\"0/10" ...`. That backslash is only printed. To see the result, wrap your call in `cat()`.